# Events vs. Pageviews

Tags: google-analytics

I know I'm probably missing something silly, but I'm trying to figure the following out.

When I run my custom reporting for Top Pageviews, Page A is my top viewed page and Page B is at #10 for Pageviews. However, when I look at Top Events, Page B is at #2 (users clicking on home page link to Page B) and Page A is further down.

Wouldn't I expect Page B to have higher pageviews than Page A, since more people are clicking to get to it?

Comment: How did you implement events on a link to leave the page?  When the page is going away events often don't get sent before it unloads.

Comment: Could people also be getting to Page A from some way other besides triggering an event, like google searches?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this more. The site is an internal tool that requires login, so Google searches would not apply, but I will ask more about how the events were implemented.